# How to pass class instances to WndProc in C#

Tags: c#, windows, wndproc

How do i pass an instance of an object which is in my main form to WndProc method

**For ex:** 
I have a ComboBox object - **objCombo**. And i have to capture a certain window message before the system draws the drop down list box.

One way to do this I can have a custom combobox which derives from the ComboBox

```
public class CustomComboBox : ComboBox 
{
   //... some initialization code goes here

   protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
   {
        if (m.Msg == WM_CTLCOLORLISTBOX)
        {
          // capture the message and do some work.
          //here i can get the reference to the CustomComboBox by using 
          //this keyword.
        }
   }

}
```

However, I want to know is there a way where in I can do this without having go through the process of creating the custom combobox and do exactly the same. i.e. capturing the Windows message inside my Form class using the reference to my combobox instance. ?

i.e.

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
   //... some initialization code goes here including the InitializeComponent 
   // for form objects and other controls 

   private void CaptureComboWndProc(ref Message m)
   {
     // this method will capture only the windows message specific to objCombo ??
   }

}
```

I hope I am being clear with the question 
Thanks and Cheers 
VATSA

Answer (score 3):

Better way is to create a descendant of combobox. Which is very clear way of doing it.

However you can find the control from message, here's how you go.

Use `Control.FromHandle` to find the control to which message is posted.

```
   protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
   {
        if (m.Msg == WM_CTLCOLORLISTBOX)
        {
            if(Control.FromHandle(m.HWnd) == this.objCombo)
            {
                CaptureComboWndProc(ref m);
            }
        }
   }

   private void CaptureComboWndProc(ref Message m)
   {

   }
```

and... Finally I'd like to say **don't** do this please.

Comment: This isn't going to work, only the ComboBox sees the message.

Comment: @HansPassant : For the specific message `WM_CTLCOLORLISTBOX` may be this won't work as you said if the message is delivered only to combobox; but this approach would work but for messages which goes through its parent.

Comment: But then it isn't any different from what the OP is already doing.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, the generic technique is called "sub-classing the window" in Windows GUI programming.  It works by replacing the window procedure of a window.  This is already done for every native window control you find back in the toolbox (ListView, ComboBox, etc), that's how they raise events.  And can be done repeatedly.  No need to pinvoke, the NativeWindow class supports it with its AssignHandle() method.

You have to derive your own class from NativeWindow and override the WndProc() method to implement custom message handling.  Use, say, the form's Load event to attach it.  Roughly:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private class ComboHooker : NativeWindow {
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
            if (m.Msg == 0x134) {
                // etc...
            }
            else {
                // Stop sub-classing on WM_NCDESTROY
                if (m.Msg == 0x82) this.ReleaseHandle();
                base.WndProc(ref m);
            }
        }
    }

    private void hookComboBoxes(Control.ControlCollection ctls) {
        foreach (Control ctl in ctls) {
            if (ctl.GetType() == typeof(ComboBox)) {
                new ComboHooker().AssignHandle(ctl.Handle);
            }
            hookComboBoxes(ctl.Controls);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
        hookComboBoxes(this.Controls);
        base.OnLoad(e);
    }
}
```